# Simulating slope coefficient for linear regression

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients

I'm currently reading an article: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4302277/#S5title

And in **Section 5** I've come across a simulation for a few estimators of the slope $\beta_1$. I wanted to start with the one obtained by least squares method:
$\hat \beta=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2}$. So I tried to recreate what was done in the article by writing a code in R:

```
mux <- 1
muy1 <- 2
muy2 <- 2.5
sigmax2 <- 1.69
sigmay12 <- 4
sigmay22 <- 6.25
cxy1 <- 0.8
cxy2 <- 0.7
n1 <- 50
n2 <- 50

library(MASS)

#generating vector of expected values and covariance matrices for bivariate normal distribution
vec_mu1 <- c(mux, muy1)
vec_mu2 <- c(mux, muy2)
sigma1 <- matrix(c(sigmax2, cxy1, cxy1, sigmay12), 2)
sigma2 <- matrix(c(sigmax2, cxy2, cxy2, sigmay22), 2)

beta <-  vector("list", 1000)
beta1 <-  vector("list", 1000)
for(i in 1:1000)
{
  data1 <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n1, mu = vec_mu1, Sigma = sigma1))
  data2 <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n2, mu = vec_mu2, Sigma = sigma2))
  names(data1) <- c("x", "y")
  names(data2) <- c("x", "y")
  beta[i] <- sum((data1$x-mean(data1$x))*(data1$y-mean(data1$y)))/sum((data1$x-mean(data1$x))^2)
 }

plot(density(unlist(beta)))
```

Unfortunately, what I get is not too close to what was obtained in the article (solid black line) - it is not centered at the real value $\beta_1 = 1.23$. I guess it's due to the fact that I do not really include this parameter in my code generating samples. Could anyone please point out what's wrong with what I did above and **how to get this true value of $\beta_1$?**

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kT3O.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive that the mistake lies in your definition of `sigma1` and `sigma2`. In the paper, the authors say "the correlations between x and y in groups 1 and 2 were set to 0.8 and 0.7 respectively", but you need to use **covariances** instead of correlation in the covariance matrix that you are supplying to `mvrnorm`.

Comment: thanks for a reply! You are absolutely right, now I pass $\sigma_{xy} = corr(X,Y)\cdot \sigma_X\cdot \sigma_Y$ instead of $corr(X,Y)$. Have you got any idea how can I get this true value of $\beta_1=1.23$?

Comment: @amal Yes, it is there in the paper as well. Equation 2.

Comment: Oh man, I'm blind. Thanks again for your help!